# Can I migrate a hard drive with the debian AMD installation?

Tags: debian, intel, amd

I can migrate my Debian installation that worked under an **AMD** processor and now that I do it on an **intel**, or do I have to do something extra?

I ask because for **AMD** I had to install several things, even for it to work GNOME I had to change configuration of **XORG**

Regards!

Comment: Are you using the same graphic card on the new pc?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the `debian` linux kernel is generic, that means it works for `intel` and `amd` processors. Your PC should boot up fine. There are optional microcode packages like `amd64-microcode` and `intel-microcode` which you should install/uninstall.

In case you did a brand change with your graphics card. Your PC will boot but might not be able to start Gnome. In this case you'd need to install the display drivers in the terminal.

**EDIT:**

thanks to @Bahamut

in case switching from BIOS to UEFI you'd need to do something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair).

Comment: Another thing to consider Bios/Uefi.

Answer (score 0):

You questions is actually two-fold, so here are two answers:

1) The underlying part of the Debian install (i.e. kernel) is the same regardless of Intel/AMD CPU. This should work regardless of vendor (as long as the Arch is the same).

2)  Your X environment depends on the graphics card and the related drivers for that vendor. In short, you will need to install the graphics drivers for the new hardware to get a working graphical environment.